# What is "Chinese Culture"?

Tags: culture

What is Chinese culture?
What does it consist of?
How would you describe it?

I've been asked what American and British culture is - and I really have no idea what it is or how to even explain it others.

I've heard from a lot of Chinese, even, that Hong Kong and Taiwan have preserved Chinese culture better than mainlanders. So what Chinese culture?

Comment: Isn't this a question for google/wikipedia?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Chinese culture not the language

Comment: Not sure this one can be answered here, the question is quite broad. Each culture can have sub cultures: culture - noun; 1 the arts and other manifestations of human intellectual achievement regarded collectively: 20th century popular culture. • a refined understanding or appreciation of this: men of culture. • the customs, arts, social institutions, and achievements of a particular nation, people, or other social group: Caribbean culture | people from many different cultures. • [ with modifier ] the attitudes and behavior characteristic of a particular social group: the emerging drug culture

Comment: common guys - I had young children tell me today that 尝粪 *is* Chinese culture...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to describe precisely what the culture is, different people give different answers. As to me, the culture is: Filial piety, jiaozi , kongfu, paper-cut, beautiful scenery.

Comment: jiaozi is sort of only popular in mandarin-speaking regions... When it comes to food and customs, China is a country divided into regions according to the dialect groups. Each dialect region has its own popular food and customs.

Comment: @user58955 - Not to mention the huge diaspora that have evolved into new Chinese culture in all countries.

Comment: Despite "offending the rules" with this being off-topic, still an interesting viewpoint by user3231931 ;-)